# Converting a query to CNF

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic, cnf

I've recently been trying to learn logic, but I've come across a query that I can't do and I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong. When converting a query to CNF, what do you do when you come to this particular situation?

```
(a AND NOT(b AND c)) AND (d OR e)
= (a AND NOT b) OR (a AND NOT c) AND (d OR e)
=
```

How would i re-arrange this to get it into CNF form? Am I doing something completely wrong?

Thanks for your help,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

I use the symbols:

```
^ for AND
v for OR 
~ for NOT
```

and here is how you can transform your formula in CNF:

```
  (a ^ ~(b ^  c)) ^ (d v e)
= (a ^ (~b v ~c)) ^ (d v e)    // DeMorgan:   ~(A ^ B) <=> (~A v ~B)
=  a ^ (~b v ~c)  ^ (d v e)
= CNF
```

Every clauses are separated by AND and contain only OR. With your syntax it gives:

```
a AND (NOT b OR NOT c) AND (d OR e)
```

I hope it helps :)